# User profile sync issues

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

"The management agent ""MOSS-UserProfile"" run profile ""MOSS_DELTAIMPORT_32f3b5c7-5bf3-4dc4-b6c4-393a2c9e111b"" completed a step with errors.

Additional Information

Discovery Errors       : ""3""

Synchronization Errors : ""0""

Metaverse Retry Errors : ""0""

Export Errors          : ""0""

Warnings               : ""1""

User Action

View the management agent run history for details."

---

The above error i picked from Event viewer.

Comment: Please provide us with more detailed error from MIISCLIENT at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\14.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe

Comment: is it causing any sync issue? did you ran the full sync?

Answer (score -1):

You need to re create the user profile service application with new databases.